# Mybatis "desc tablename" not working. Getting error as "The error occurred while setting parameters"

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

**Queries.xml**

```
<select id="getDBDetails" parameterType="String" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
                desc ${value}
</select>
```

**MainRunner.java**

```
 List<k> list=commonQuery.getDataFromDB("getDBDetails","TABLENAME");
```

Above code works fine for other queries.

But it does not work for 'desc TABLENAME'.

I am getting following exception :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESCRIBE` is not a valid SQL statement. It is a SQL*Plus command so you can't execute it via JDBC.

If you want to get table metadata via JDBC use metadata API like this:

```
Connection connection = ...;
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null,null, tableName, null);
while(columns.next())
{
    String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    String datatype = columns.getString("DATA_TYPE");
    String columnsize = columns.getString("COLUMN_SIZE");
    String decimaldigits = columns.getString("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
    String isNullable = columns.getString("IS_NULLABLE");
    String is_autoIncrment = columns.getString("IS_AUTOINCREMENT");
}
```

See [docmentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for details.